# How can I download generated PDF by html-pdf-node library, node and React JS and graphQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql

I am getting response from the backend now how can I download the generated PDF from the frontend by clicking on the Export button.
My Export button click handler as follows;

```
const handleExportProjectData = () => {
const changeStatusProjectData = JSON.stringify(project);
dataProvider
  .postRequest("ExportAllProjectChangeStatus", {
    queryType: "retrieve",
    data: { changeStatusProjectData },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data, "data posted");
    saveChangeReport(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    notify("No change status data found to export");
  });
 };
```

and my backend code is;

```
const downloadChangeStatusPDF = async (root, { changeStatusProjectData },{ user }) => {
  const html_to_pdf = require("html-pdf-node");
  let options = { format: "A4" };
  let today = new Date();
  let dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
  let mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0"); //January is 0!
  let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  today = dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy;


 let file = { content: "<h1>Welcome to html-pdf-node</h1>" };



 let generatedPDF = await html_to_pdf.generatePdf(file, options)
    .then((pdfBuffer) => {
        return JSON.stringify(pdfBuffer);
    });
 return generatedPDF;
};
```

I am getting the following response in my console as follows;
[console.log(response.data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kchvo.jpg)

now my question is how can I download the generated PDF using `saveChangeReport` function?

Answer (score 0):

Alhamdulillah! I have solved the problem simply by converting the buffer into base64 then converting the base64 into PDF.

Comment: Thank you very much that you have showed me a possibly better way. Can you please demonstrate with an example that how can I save this binary file as PDF?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).